# Instantiate Javabean

Tags: java, jsp, session

Hi is this the correct way to instantiate a javabean? in school, we are taught to use the
`<% usebean id="something" class="package.java" ...%>` xml tag.

However in some tutorials, i see people are using this:

```
<th>Welcome <%UserBean currentUser = (UserBean)session.getAttribute("currentSessionUser"));%><%= currentUser.getUsername()%></th>
```

is it advisable to do the above code in jsp?

Comment: what you are taught in school is old-schooled. I have not seen code like that in the last 5 years. The last time I see that is, i think, 8 years ago.

Answer (score 0):

For the code below that you have written in scriptlet. you can use the following jsp syntax for the same.

```
<jsp:userBean id="currentSessionUser" class="userbeanpackage.UserBean" />
```